# Cannot set UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I want to have `UILabel`, but for some reason when I do `theLabel.text` it does not work. But my first label does.

Is there a issue in the code?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *Screen;

    IBOutlet UILabel *Operations;

}
```

Then I would use it like the following:

```
Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

Operations.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(The operation selected)"];
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Be specific. Describe _in detail_ what you expect, what actually happens, and what you've done to try to fix it.

Comment: Are the IBOutlets connected to the labels?

Comment: @skladek                                                                    they are connected to the outlets.

Comment: @JoshCaswell  well in the viewcontroller.m it can't find Operations.text

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have connected the two labels.

You can see that by looking at the little dots. In this case they are left to
line number 13 and 15.

If they are "filled" they have a connection.

[image: Check the dots]

If they are not filled like the picture below, it means there is no connection. In most cases you would have renamed the property. (Shame on apple, for not retaining the connection) 
(In the picture you should notice that I have renamed the property)

[image]

One thing that can confuse people, is that even though there are no valid connection,
interface builder still says there is.

You should just click the little x button and start over.

[image]

You can do that by dragging the little dot from the property onto the interface builder object.

[image]

Comment: `stringWithFormat:` only _requires_ one argument. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(The operation selected)"];` is valid.